Взаимодействие OTG printer с android
Всем здравствуйте. Кто-нибудь может пожалуйста подсказать, как из кода java android распечатать pdf-файл без написания низкоуровневого драйвера на С на принтер USB OTG? Canon LBP 6030. Нужно через одно устройство все сделать, но без написания драйверов.
Требуется сделать из кода. Есть такие приложения как NokoPrint и PrinterShare, которые  без проблем находят принтер, но это приложение и их gui, недоступность из кода. Есть ещё одна либа, там доступен бесшовный сдк, но лицензия на одно устройство не мало стоит

то ли данный вопрос, то ли вот этот - какой-то из них - явно дубликат.
